# How does WebPagetest measure load time?

Tags: webpagetest

I've been looking at the timing.navigation api and it looks like the standard way to measure the page load time is: 
  timing.loadEventEnd - timing.navigationStart

From the WebPagetest docs:
The Load Time is measured as the time from the start of the initial navigation until the beginning of the window load event (onload).

My question is two part:
Is the WebPagetest load time calculation equivalent to: 
  timing.loadEventStart - timing.navigationStart  ?

And, if it is equivalent to the above, do we have a discrepancy between what it does and others in the industry?

Answer (score 0):

You should check [these question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045767/page-load-time-with-javascript) to know how to calculate the load time yourself in JS.

About how does WebPageTest to achieve that, it actually use real browsers to load and render the pages. It then has (among other things) [a browser plugin called **wptdriver**](https://sites.google.com/a/webpagetest.org/docs/private-instances#TOC-wptdriver-Chrome-Firefox-Safari-IE-6-) to catch browsers developer tools information including the load time event.