# How to clear timeline selection in Chrome dev tools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

How to clear selectin on the timeline?
If I do double click then selection will be expanded to the end of the timeline, but new request still will be filtered out. So only close and reopen dev tools window works for me.[image]

Chrome 89.0.4389.72

Comment: It can't be cleared.

Comment: I thought i was the only one who accidentally clicked on this thing! Praise be to the internet!

Answer (score 6):

Double Click the marker OR Mouse Wheel Scroll Down

[image]

Comment: This action will expand filter to the end of current window area. If you will refresh page you will see that filter still there.

Answer (score 4):

## Summary

Toggle "Stop Network recording" off and on again to *reset the timeline selector*. Note: This clears previous network requests, which is similar to @Raf's suggestion to close and re-open dev tools. Toggling "Stop Network recording" is slightly better than closing and re-opening dev tools because it doesn't clear/reset *other* dev tools context (like Recordings on the Recording tab).

[image: toggle stop/start network recording]

## Detail

### "Double-clicking" doesn't work

The first animation below shows how "double click the marker or mouse-wheel scroll down" (from [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70987989/1175496)), doesn't work (as @Raf --the OP-- says). It *seems* to work (double-clicking expands the timeline selection), **but any subsequent requests appear *outside* the timeline selection.**

[image: double click on network tab timeline seems to clear the selection, but subsequent requests are outside the selection]

### "Toggle Stop/Start Network recording" works, but clears past requests

The second animation below shows how toggling "Stop/Start Network recording" will reset the selector; subsequent requests are all *inside* the timeline selection.

This clears any *previous* requests (like closing-and-reopening dev tools will do) but this approach is slightly better -- because any active "Recordings" on "Recorder" tab continue to record.

[image: toggle stop/start network recording will clear past requests but also clear the timeline selection]